# How to add a column that count the number of appearances of the unique characters from the previous columns?

Tags: r

I have such a dataframe

```
mydf <- data.frame(Y1 = c('3','3','6','6'),Y2 = c('3','3','3','3'), 
Y3 = c('3','3','3','6'),Y4 = c('3','3','6','6'),Y5 = c('7','6','6','6'),
Y6 = c('7','8','8','8'),Y7 = c('7','6','3','8'),Y8 = c('7','8','8','7'),
Y9 = c('10','10','8','7'),Y10 = c('10','10','8','7'))
```

which is

```
   Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7 Y8 Y9 Y10
1  3  3  3  3  7  7  7  7  10 10
2  3  3  3  3  6  8  6  8  10 10
3  6  3  3  6  6  8  3  8  8  8
4  6  3  6  6  6  8  8  7  7  7
```

These are the coordinates of the soccer players on  the field (goalkeeper excluded).
I want to add one more column 'Formation' that computes the number of appearances of coordinate numbers from previous columns in order to yield the football formation.

For example, for line one, there are four 3s, four 7s, and two 10s, which should yield the formation of 4-4-2

Also, some coordinate number may not appear together. For line 3, '6' appears in Y1,Y4, and Y5.

> Basically, the general pattern for formation should be a-b-c(-d-e), where a,b,c,d,e denotes the number of appearances of the first,second,third(fourth,fifth,if applicable) *unique* number, respectively.

For example, for this dataset, the result should yield:

```
       Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7 Y8 Y9 Y10 Formation
    1  3  3  3  3  7  7  7  7  10 10  4-4-2
    2  3  3  3  3  6  8  6  8  10 10  4-2-2-2
    3  6  3  3  6  6  8  3  8  8  8   3-3-4
    4  6  3  6  6  6  8  8  7  7  7   4-1-2-3
```

Comment: Please do try for a _complete_ explanation of all possible alternatives. Is {3,6,7,8,10} a complete list of "positions"? And would there be a difference in formation summary for `c(3  3  3  3  7  7  7  7  10 10)` and `c(3  3  3  3  7  7  7  7  8 8)`? And if you read the Help pages you will find that chatty introductions and conclusions are echewed.

Answer (score 2):

We can loop through the rows, get the frequency count with `table`, `paste` the frequency together to create the 'Formation' column.

```
df1$Formation <- apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) 
         paste(table(factor(x, levels=unique(x))), collapse="-"))
df1$Formation
#[1] "4-4-2"   "4-2-2-2" "3-3-4"   "4-1-2-3"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table` you can

```
library(data.table)
wide <- setDT(mydf, keep.rownames = TRUE)  
long <-  melt(wide, id.vars = "id")
formation <- long[, .N, by = .(id, value)][, .(Formation = paste(N, collapse = "-")), by = id]
wide[formation, on = "id"][, id := NULL][]

#   Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7 Y8 Y9 Y10 Formation
#1:  3  3  3  3  7  7  7  7 10  10     4-4-2
#2:  3  3  3  3  6  8  6  8 10  10   4-2-2-2
#3:  6  3  3  6  6  8  3  8  8   8     3-3-4
#4:  6  3  6  6  6  8  8  7  7   7   4-1-2-3
```

### Explanation

- The data.frame is coerced to data.table while adding row ids.
- After reshaping to long form, the number of appearances are counted group-wise by row id and coordinate. `Formation` is created by collapsing the counts in a string for each row id.
- Finally, the result is joined with the data.table we started with. The row id column is removed as it is no longer needed.